# Postgresql add item in array except if null

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I try to make a PostgreSQL array by using values from JSONB field.

When all data are in JSONB, result is fine. This query :

```
SELECT array [
    (SELECT ('{"tech_id": 4, "admin_id": 5}'::jsonb->>'admin_id')::int),
    (SELECT ('{"tech_id": 4, "admin_id": 5}'::jsonb->>'tech_id')::int)
];
```

returns me the right result because **admin_id** and **tech_id** are in JSONB field :

```
-[ RECORD 1 ]
array | {5,4}
```

But, if JSONB contains only one value, the array contains a NULL value.
This query :

```
SELECT array [
    (SELECT ('{"tech_id": 4}'::jsonb->>'admin_id')::int),
    (SELECT ('{"tech_id": 4}'::jsonb->>'tech_id')::int)
];
```

Gives me this result :

```
-[ RECORD 1 ]---
array | {NULL,4}
```

But I want an array like **{4}**, so **without NULL value**.
Do you know a way to avoid adding NULL value in this case ?

Comment: You can use `jsonb_strip_nulls()`: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html

Comment: Thank you for your comment... but I get others error. I found another solution that I will post here. I hope this solution is good. Thank you again :)
Add informations : I test your solution with syntaxes like **SELECT json_strip_nulls(array_to_json(array [**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finnaly, I found solution by wrapping the array to check if values are NULL.
I use the following code :

```
select array_agg(id) FROM unnest(array [
    (SELECT ('{"tech_id": 4}'::jsonb->>'admin_id')::int),
    (SELECT ('{"tech_id": 4}'::jsonb->>'tech_id')::int)
]) as id where id IS NOT NULL;
```

PostgreSQL returns the expected result :

```
-[ RECORD 1 ]--
array_agg | {4}
```